# An 8 line riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I have a harvesting tool,
But I'm not collecting food,
I come in uninvited,
But no one calls me rude.

My dress code is dark,
Body is stark,
Clothed in a cloak,
Terrorising innocent folk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be:

> The Death

I have a harvesting tool,

> The Death is represented with a scythe

But I'm not collecting food,

> He's not collecting food

I come in uninvited,

> It's never expected or wanted

But no one calls me rude.

> Not sure on this.

My dress code is dark,

> Represented usually in black

Body is stark,

> Often represented as a skeleton

Clothed in a cloak,

> And wearing a cloak

Terrorising innocent folk.

> Nobody likes him

Comment: Correct. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

This riddle is about

> The Grim Reaper, AKA Death

I have a harvesting tool

> A sickle

But I'm not collecting food,

> He's collecting souls,

I come in uninvited

> No one wants to die

But no one calls me rude.

> Yet everybody accepts that everyone will die one day.

My dress code is dark

> The Grim Reaper always wears black and/or dark grey colours exclusively

Body is stark,

> His body is a skeleton,

Clothed in a cloak,

> The Grim Reaper is always clothed as a hooded figure wearing a cloak,

Terrorising innocent folk.

> Even the innocent must die too eventually.

Comment: Unfortunately you are a bit late in answering this question